# Issue with markdown edit viewing

Tags: discussion, bug, suggested-edits, markdown

Pls take a look at [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3024506).

When the edit view style is set to `rendered-output` it shows that i added appropraite indentation

but when it is set to `markdown`, it shows that i canceled a lot of the post and then re-wrote it. (which might tempt a user to reject the edit as `Changing too much in the post`.

Please is this the normal behaviour of markdown editing or is it a bug?

Comment: Explaining this in the Review Comments is probably a good idea.

Comment: @AmalMurali How do i add review comments?

Comment: [Like this](http://i.imgur.com/cQWta4W.png).

Comment: Not an answer, but when I review I am in the habit of checking both views. This is especially true if there *appear* to be significant changes. In this case, I definitely would have toggled the view from "markdown" to "rendered output".